# Undefined get_header function

Tags: templates, page-template, headers

I installed wordpress according to the site https://ipipe.ru/info/ustanovka-wordpress-na-openserver and then wanted to use underscores.me, where I entered worldelectronics and pressed the generate button (as a result, a request appeared to overwrite the wordpress files).

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\OSPanel\domains\worldelectronics.ru\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\worldelectronics.ru\index.php on line 15

Below is the index.php file

```
    <?php
    /**
     * The main template file
     *
     * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
     * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
     * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
     * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
     *
     * @package WorldElectronics
     */

    get_header();
    ?>

        <main id="primary" class="site-main">

            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :

                if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
                    ?>
                    <header>
                        <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header>
                    <?php
                endif;

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

                endwhile;

                the_posts_navigation();

            else :

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

            endif;
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->

    <?php
    get_sidebar();
    get_footer();
```

How to get the main page of the worldelectronics theme taken from underscores.me to display?

Answer (score 1):

What you downloaded was not a replacement for WordPress, it was a theme. Themes need to go inside the `wp-content/themes` folder. Once a theme folder is placed correctly it should appear as an option in the theme menu in WP Admin where you can preview and activate it.

In the meantime, you need to reinstall WordPress to undo the damage you caused by overwriting the root with a theme. The only time you should modify files in `wp-admin`, `wp-includes` or at the top level, are when you're updating to a new version of WordPress ( the only exception is `wp-config.php` ). All customisation and additions go in themes and plugins located in the `wp-content/themes` and `wp-content/plugins` folders.